# owncloud app navigation from sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, owncloud

I am newbie to the owncloud app development. I am trying to do a simple app in the owncloud environment.

In my app I created the basic things like `appinfo` file and `index.php` file and enabled the app also. So now I want to implement the navigation from sidebar and the page should not reload (like in file or activity app). I am using the owncloud API's only. Now I stuck there only. I'm not able to navigate the pages without refreshing. I am trying to understand the javascript files but I am not getting anything in that.
For this please suggest me what all things I should do and learn? And how it can be implemented.

P.S: I read owncloud official document (developer manual) but that has not helped me.

Comment: I don't know much about app development myself, but I've found the people in the [#owncloud-dev irc channel over at freenode](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=owncloud-dev) always to be helpful!

Comment: You say it works with Files and Activity app – so, did you have had a look at them?

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Old Menu" app that you can install on your server yourself. More info is here: https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/Old+menu?content=166872

[image: Old Menu App]

Comment: But he wants to create an own app as I understood.